# How to prevent a slideshow's figcaption from jumping up and down as each image loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading, slideshow

I've spent a horrendous amount of time on this.

I'm using

```
<!-- phased loading of images -->
<script src="lazysizes.min.js" async=""></script>
```

At Google's optimising suggestion, so images only load as the user can actually see them.  However this means the browser is unable to layout the page in advance and therefore moves page elements around as images load.  I've solved some of this by specifying a height on my image box so the whole page doesn't leap up and down.

Sadly though the figcaption at the bottom of each slide continues to leap up and down, whilst the browser fetches the next image.  I've tried various ways of specifying a height on each slideshow image, using my mySlidesV class, but google seemingly just ignores that till it's loaded.

Because I'm loading images of different dimensions based on media queries my css is getting ever more complicated, what's the most robust and clean way of fixing this?

This is a sample of the slideshow:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
<picture class="mySlidesV">
        <source media="(max-width: 374px)" data-srcset="imagesIndex/slideshow-vertical/victoria-street-cropped-540.webp" type="image/webp">
        <source data-srcset="imagesIndex/slideshow-vertical/victoria-street-wide-540.webp" type="image/webp">       
        <source media="(max-width: 374px)" data-srcset="imagesIndex/slideshow-vertical/victoria-street-cropped-540_guetzli.jpg">
        <img data-src="imagesIndex/slideshow-vertical/victoria-street-wide-540_guetzli.jpg" alt="A Harry Potter tour dressed in cosplay poses on Victoria Street" class="lazyload"/>
  <figcaption class="slides-vertical">Victoria Street, reputed to be the inspiration for Diagon Alley. Over summer we stop here for Scottish ice-cream; this class just had a standard Cheering charm, I love a fizzy brain</figcaption>
</picture>

<picture class="mySlidesV">
        <source data-srcset="imagesIndex/slideshow-vertical/floating-witch-540.webp" type="image/webp">
        <img data-src="imagesIndex/slideshow-vertical/floating-witch-540_guetzli.jpg" alt="Young Witch in a Sorting Hat floats in mid air above Princes Street Edinburgh, the Castle in the background" class="lazyload">

  <figcaption class="slides-vertical">Had a young witch on the tour today, she doesn't even need a broom</figcaption>
</picture>

  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivsV(-1)"><span style="color: white;">&#10094;</span></button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivsV(1)"><span style="color: white;">&#10095;</span></button>
</div>
```

I'm using W3c's slideshow here: `https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp`

Comment: Give a min-height to your .mySlidesV class and make figcaption position absolute to bottom. I hope, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can always HIDE `figcaption` on page load, using the lazyload class and the next selector for figcaption. Once lazysizes loads the image, it removes the `lazyload` class from the image, which will ignore the below CSS and allow the figcaption to be displayed AFTER the image has been displayed.

```
.lazyload + figcaption{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Ah wow, that's a really thoughful solution. Sadly I can't get it working.  Figcaption is not actually a child of the .lazyload class, so I tried <figcaption class="lazyload">, but that didn't work either, well probably loads instantly, whilst the browser fetches the img.  I also tried tranfering the lazyload class, to figcaption's parent giving: <picture class="mySlidesV lazyload"> but that didn't work either.  Lazyload works on <img> tags only I think.

Comment: Would there be a way to put it in the javascript lazysizes.min.js file?  Something like document.getElementsByClassName("figcaption").... do something?

Comment: @Sam the `+` sign in my css is the `next` selector which means that figcaption has to be the next element after `.lazyload` element like in your original post.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @imvain, it's a really intelligent insightful solution, unfortunately, I can't get it working, the figcaption still jumps to the top till the next image loads.  I tried putting your css betwixt the <style> tags in the html file and in my styles.css, both failed.  I've tried position: absolute, which did work, but when the figcaption is several lines the picture then loads over it, so it is no good.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("figure").forEach(figure => {
    const img = figure.querySelector("img");
    if (!img.complete) {
        const elements = figure.querySelectorAll("figcaption");
        elements.forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
        img.onload = (ev) => elements.forEach(e => e.style.removeProperty("display"));
    }
});
```

Instead of using `display` (which may conflict with your css that already defines a `display` for your `figcaption` you can use `opacity` or `visibility`.

Ideally it could be built-in with an attribute on `figcaption` (`depends-on-img="true"`).

Answer (score 0):

I know this old, but since I also just stuggled with this here is my solution. It is kind of the opposite of @imvain2's approach. Instead of hiding the figcaption when the images has lazyload class, I hide the figcaption by default only showing it if the image has lazyloaded class which it will only get when they have been loaded. See image below.

[image]

```
figcaption {
display: none;
}

.lazyloaded + figcaption{
    display:block;
}
```